# Child node values are null while retrieving the firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve the database values but the data in node/child which I fetched using uID is null. 
    Here is my code -

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            currentUser = extras.getString("currentUser");
            selectedUser = extras.getString("selectedUser");
            uID = extras.getString("uID");
    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();


mDbReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    final DatabaseReference uidRef = mDbReference.child("users").child(uID);

    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {


@Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                ChatMessageModel chatMessageModel = ds.getValue(ChatMessageModel.class);
                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: " + uidRef);
                Log.d("users:: ", chatMessageModel.getMsgContent());
                    messageList.add(chatMessageModel);
                    for (int i = 0; i < messageList.size(); i++) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "All received messages : " + messageList.get(i).getMsgContent());

                    }
                }
                chatAppMsgAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                //Do what you need to do with the list.
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
            }
        };
        uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

//and here is my database
 u0TddklO8BXKCRHp4UFXEvmPS1H3: null
//u0TddklO8BXKCRHp4UFXEvmPS1H3 is uid. where, uid is of currentuser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the `user1` is the corresponding `uid` of the first user, to get all those `ChatMessageModel` objects beneath your `user1` node, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("users").child(uid);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        ArrayList<ChatMessageModel> messageList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            ChatMessageModel chatMessageModel = ds.getValue(ChatMessageModel.class);
            Log.d("users:: ", chatMessageModel.getMsgContent());
            messageList.add(chatMessageModel);
        }

        //Do what you need to do with the list.
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
    }
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Comment: Hey, I tried above solution but I am facing same issue. Error is - java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference.   But the value of UID is not null in my case.

Comment: DatabaseReference uidRef = mDbReference.child("users").child(uID);
this line is returning null.

Comment: Can you please edit your question with your updated code, to see the problem more clearly?

Comment: hello I edited the code and null pointer issue is resolved. but retrieved child is null.

Comment: The fact that you get another error, it means that the initial error disappeared and this are good news :) but this sounds as a new issue which basically should be considered another question that I cannot responde in a comment or using only the the data above. As a personal guess, I think that you are using a wrong database reference but in order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question using a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so me and other users can help you.

Comment: I have asked the fresh question please suggest answer. But I am not using wrong database reference. I have cross checked that. thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: It was only a guess. I'll take a look and if I'll know the answer, I'll write it to you. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

1. First of all try debugging the app by setting your Firebase database rule as the following -

   ```
   {
      "rules": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true
      }
   }
   ```
2. Still if it doesn't work, try doing this -

   ```
   private FirebaseDatabase database;
   private DatabaseReference databaseRef;

   database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
   databaseRef = database.getReference("users");

   databaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
               Log.d("Output Key", snapshot.getKey());
               Log.d("Output Value", snapshot.getValue().toString());
           }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
   });
   ```

Comment: Hey, I tried above solution but I am facing same issue. Error is - java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference. But the value of UID is not null in my case.

Comment: Can you put your complete code?? I hope you are declaring databaseRef as a Global variable and initialising that inside your onCreate method.

Comment: Hello, null pointer exception issue is solved. It is just bcz of I am trying to fetch values from previous activity and after that I defined databaseRef and I declared databaseRef is global. Thank you very much for help.